# How to create global company policy that will set user photos from folder in WS AD

Tags: windows, group-policy, users

I want to set user profile pictures on logon screen via policy. How can something like that be made?
I have all photos in one folder, for each employee. Is there an easy way to do that?
I'm using Windows Server 2008 Active Directory.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may set the login- and lock-screen images by:

- Run *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen*
- Set the Background drop-down to "Slideshow"
- Click "Add a folder"
- Navigate to the folder and click OK to select.

Comment: Not really. I have one photo for each user in domain and I want the policy to automate the whole process.